# Specify Java CLASSPATH variable

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am not familiar with Java and I am trying to run a piece of Java code packaged as jar file.

On Windows command line, I specify the CLASSPATH to my jar folder like this:

```
set CLASSPATH="D:\jarFolder"
```

And there's a test.jar file in that folder. But when I run this

```
java -jar test.jar
```

it still failed with this error:

```
Unable to access jarfile test.jar
```

I can run the test.jar by specify the full path. But I want to know why the CLASSPATH doesn't work. My understanding is, it tells the java runtime where to locate the jar file.

Comment: Both answers are 100% correct, so I have no idea why they aren't "useful".

Comment: I didn't mark them down. Someone else did it.

Answer (score 0):

Jarfiles have to be on the classpath explicitly. Specifying a classpath dir for a jarfile is not sufficient.

See the [related Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#CBBIJCHG) on the Java command line:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Comment: I tried this `set CLASSPATH="D:\jarFolder\test.jar"`, still the same error if I use `java -jar test.jar`, but it works if I specify the package name like this `java a.b.ClassName`. Don't know why...

Comment: Are you specifying the start class? Setting the jarfile explicitly on the classpath is supported, and is the only way to invoke a class that is not the main class in the manifest.

Comment: Yes, I am specifying the start class. I am just confused why it cannot combine the CLASSPATH folder and the test.jar file name to make a fullpath.

Comment: The implementation of the java optarg processor precludes this, as explained in the link I provided. The classpath shows the VM how to find the jarfile, which is treated as an unexploded zipfile without a manifest. Then you have to tell the VM where your specific main() happens to be.  The coward's answer is "as designed" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
java -jar D:\jarFolder\test.jar
```

If you know main class name of your entry point of jar. You can use

```
 set CLASSPATH="D:\jarFolder"
 java yourpackage.yourEntryPoint
```

You can learn your entry point of your jar file using a zip program to extract jar file and reading  [file entry point section of manifest.mf file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

When you use -jar option, you need to specify which jar. Think of it this way. If you do not give jar name, which jar java should execute? You may have 10,20 may be 100 jars in your class path.

But if you give class name, then java searches among jars and execute correct one.

Comment: I tried this `set CLASSPATH="D:\jarFolder\test.jar"`, still the same error if I use `java -jar test.jar`, but it works if I specify the package name like this `java a.b.ClassName`. Don't know why...

Comment: My question is, how does the java runtime figure out the jar fullpath?

Comment: Because the argument to java is the start class, and you are supplying it as it is found in the manifest file. java -jar .... is just a convenience around adding a jarfile to the classpath and calling java on the fully qualified start class identified in the manifest file of the jar.